# Align text centrally on the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I want to have a text aligned centrally on the bottom of the page.

I have the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="position: relative">
            <p style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; width:100%; text-align: center"> bla bla
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works fine in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE.

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but you're missing a double quote: `text-align: center;">`

Comment: Adding the second " makes it work fine in IE9.

Comment: @Kevin Anthony Oppegaard Rose Sry, it was a copy and paste issue. Still doesn't work on IE 9.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a doctype as the very first line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

Without it, IE is using [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) which emulates IE 5.5 (which [doesn't support `position: fixed`](http://caniuse.com/css-fixed)).

Answer (score 1):

Might be a copy and paste issue but you need an ending quote in your `<p style=... >`, that should help.  Another option is the set your `text-align: center` on the actual `<div>` so your aligning the text inside the div. Both of these worked in IE 9 - what version of IE are you using that it's not working in?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="position: relative">
      <p style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; width:100%; text-align: center"> bla bla</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

OR

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="position: relative; text-align: center">
      <p style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; width:100%;"> bla bla</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For some reason the text is slightly shifted to the right instead of staying exactly in the middle.